# java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM pets

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, cursor

i have an error in my application.

I'm new in making apps for android, so i don´t now what's wrong...

this is in the log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM pets
```

i have  a SQLite database in which is this method:

```
public List<Pet> getAllPets() {
    List<Pet> petList = new ArrayList<Pet>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PETS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Pet pet = new Pet();
            pet.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            pet.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            pet.setAge(cursor.getString(2));
            petList.add(pet);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return petList;     
}
```

and then i'am using this method from database in other activity to fill the ListView by the names of every pet....

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    PetListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    MyDatabaseHelper db = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
    String [] items = new String[db.getPetsCount()];

    List<Pet> pets = db.getAllPets();
    for (int i = 0; i < db.getPetsCount(); i++) {
        items[i] = pets.get(i).getName();                   
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, items);
    PetListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

when this activity starts the application crashes down..

Please, can you tell me what's worng? How can i fix it? Thanks a much for help.

EDIT:

getPetsCount() method:

```
public int getPetsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PETS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    return cursor.getCount();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the getPetsCount() method ?

Comment: close the cursor and also close the database ex:db.close(). You might have called the db creation method somewhere at other place too. That is you are getting the exception, i feel.

Comment: @kumar Where i should close the database and cursor? I tried to close the cursor as fiddler answered on my question and it didn't help. It still throws the same exception....

Comment: if db.getPetsCount(); This method has db closing statement. then you have to get the database connection once again before you execute  db.getAllPets(). So better close db in getPetsCount(). And again open database connection before getAllPets() method is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i solved this by myself at the end by replace the getPetsCount method:

```
public int getPetsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PETS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return count;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should close your cursor once you have finished to use it (that may solve your issue)

```
public List<Pet> getAllPets() {
List<Pet> petList = new ArrayList<Pet>();
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PETS;

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Pet pet = new Pet();
        pet.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        pet.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        pet.setAge(cursor.getString(2));
        petList.add(pet);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

// Close cursor when finished using it
cursor.close();

return petList;     
}
```